Is there a way to encrypt a column in SQL Server?
Yes I can do the encryption myself. But is there a way to tell SQL Server (and Azure SQL Database) to encrypt a column and it then handles encrypting it on a save and decrypting it on a read?
This is for a column that is not indexed and will never be part of a where clause. I use Entity Framework Core hitting SQL Server (on our dev systems) and Azure SQL Database on our QA and production systems.

Do you want the server itself to know the encryption? You can just use TDE or BitLocker on the whole database. If you want to have the encryption only accessible to client-side code which has the key then use Always Encrypted column encryption.

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [dba.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again).

SQL Server supports transparent client-side column encryption with Always Encrypted.
You can also use EF Value Conversions to store data in a column in a format different than it appears in the entity.  So you could have an encrypted varbinary column in SQL Server and a decrypted string in C#.

That Value Conversion is interesting. Not for encryption (Always Encrypted looks perfect for that) but to map complex objects into the database. So thanks for providing both links.
